# Angularjs - add ng-* attributes using directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to add simple ng-mouseover bindings  to elements managed by directives. But colud not get it working.

@ http://jsbin.com/aqibij/2/edit

I've tried to recompile the element after adding ng-mouseover binding. directive.compile and outer controller runs, but directive.linker does not run.

@ http://jsbin.com/ikebed/1/edit

I've moved the $compile'ing into linker. It runs fine, ng-mouseover runs fine, but recompiling in linker causes endless loop, which crashes the browser at the end :)

How can I add ng-* bindings to elements using directives? What am I doing wrong in these approaches?

Comment: Have you tried directly by adding a binding to the element instead of an attribute : `element.bind('mouseover', function(e){bager()});` ? I modified a bit your code, check this here : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/NYtNV/ (I wrote into the console, alerts made me crazy)

Comment: @DotDotDot Sorry for the alerts :) I was trying to use angular all the way, to learn better,  without using jquery goodies or event binding like element.bind. What I was doing wrong is recompiling the  element with the directive tag, which caused endless loops. Inserting a child into editable div and compiling it instead of parent solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Would be great to see the final code...

Comment: @Patrick I don't remember the exact code but it was something like this http://jsbin.com/uLEQiPA/1/edit

Answer (score 4):

I assumed you were in the same boat as me, but perhaps you aren't. Either way, here are the two solutions. I was stuck on the second.

### 1) Directive for specific element

If you know the element you are dealing with is going to be a div, span, h1, whatever - or it doesn't matter (taking one element and replacing it with what you need it to be).

#### HTML

```
<div data-mydirective>
    <span>some other stuff</span>
    <div>more stuff</div>
</div>
```

#### Directive

```
module.directive( 'mydirective', [ function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        controller: function( $scope ) {
            $scope.test = function() {
                console.log('howdy');
            }
        },
        template: "<div data-ng-transclude data-ng-mouseover='test()'></div>",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {

        }
    };
}]);
```

#### Outputs

```
<div ng-mouseover="test()" data-ng-transclude="" data-mydirective="">
    <span class="ng-scope">some other stuff</span>
    <div class="ng-scope">more stuff</div>
</div>
```

### 2) Directive for an unspecific element

This is the problem I was facing. Basically, if you have a directive which could be on an h1, h2, span, div, nav, etc and you want to add your `ng-*` and attributes from within the directive.

You can't use a `template` because you don't know what the element is. Don't want to take a `h1` and replace it with a `div` right? This is why I was going down the compile route. Well, the `template` can actually be a function which we can access `element` and `attrs`.

#### Directive

```
module.directive( 'mydirective', [ function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        controller: function( $scope ) {
            $scope.test = function() {
                console.log('howdy');
            }
        },
        template: function( element, attrs ) {
            var tag = element[0].nodeName;
            return "<"+tag+" data-ng-transclude data-ng-mouseover='test()></"+tag+">";
        },
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {

        }       
    }   
}]);
```

#### HTML/Output

Same as above. Change the `div` element in your HTML to a `nav`, and the output will mirror the change.