# AngularJs Directive to add Attributes, the events are not triggered

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Good morning everybody,

I'm a bit stuck on this directive, what I want is to receive a JSON string from the getProperties function like:

```
{"class":"someclass","ng-change":"someChange()",ng-click": "someCLick()"}
```

The directive will create all the attributes present in the JSON(and it works), the problem is the ng-* doesn't work at all.... any ideas??

HTML:

```
 <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <input  type="text" ng-model="ngModel[field.fieldName]" ng-switch="text" property="{{formParams.getProperties(field.fieldName)}}" update-attr />
</div>
```

This is the directive:

```
 .directive('updateAttr', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            scope:{
                test:'&'
            },
            terminate:true,

            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                if (angular.isDefined(attrs['property']) || attrs['property'].lenght != 0) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(attrs['property']);
                    elem.removeAttr('property');
                    angular.forEach(json, function (value, key) {
                            elem.attr(key, value);
                    });
                }
            },
        };
    })
```

here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nyyfmd0e/16/

Comment: Check your for-each 
`angular.forEach(json, function (value, key) {
   console.log("ADD " + key);
   elem.attr(key, value);
});`

You add "something1" as key, with the given values - how shall that work?

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to reach, could you elaborate? At the moment your ngModel refers to an empty object is that desirable?

Comment: @Linial this script is part of something bigger, so i had to extract the directive and create a working example ^^, if you look at the js fiddle, you can see that the directive correctly create the new attribute.... but on ng-change the function test() is  not called in the directive or the controller....

Comment: It seems like another way to do so is with a template, have you tried it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206809/angularjs-add-ng-attributes-using-directives

Comment: I have thought about that solution, but because I'll have different kind of input,select etc.... and before redo everything i wanted to see if there was a way that i didn't thought ^_^

Comment: Your elem.attr isn't binding the right properties, like i wrote above, check this please.

Comment: it does ADD style ADD ng-change ADD style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your adding the `ng-change` attribute during the `link` function, after the directive has been compiled, therefore Angular is not aware if its existence. You need to recompile and replace the element of the directive after you add the new attributes.

Try replacing your directive with the code below.

```
.directive('updateAttr', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        terminate: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (angular.isDefined(attrs['property']) && attrs['property'].lenght != 0) {
                var json = JSON.parse(attrs['property']);
                angular.forEach(json, function (value, key) {
                    elem.attr(key, value);
                });
                elem.removeAttr('property');
                var $e = $compile(elem[0].outerHTML)(scope); // <-- recompile
                elem.replaceWith($e); // <-- replace with new compiled element
            }
        },
        controller:function($scope){
            $scope.test=function(){
                console.log('me either');
            }                
        }
    };
});
```

In this case the `test()` function in the directive controller will be called. If you remove the directive controller, then one your application's controller (called `testController` in your Fiddle) will be invoked.

Here a working Fiddle for your reference http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyEstilles/3oaha6z4/.