# AngularJs Directive to add Attributes, while watching the changes stuck in a loop

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

This question is related to the previous one 
[AngularJs Directive to add Attributes, the events are not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200898/angularjs-directive-to-add-attributes-the-events-are-not-triggered)

Thanks to my other question now any ng-* attribute get executed correctly, but I found myself against a wall, I need to watch property so I commented the removeAttribute, but the problem now is that it get stuck is some $compile loop .... I think it keep replacing the html tag and because I haven't removed property everything start again, until I get the error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!


.directive('updateAttr', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    replace: true,
                    priority: 10,
                    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                        function IsJsonString(str) {
                            var json = "";
                            try {
                                json = JSON.parse(str);
                            } catch (e) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            return json;
                        }
                        scope.$watch(function () {
                            return elem.attr('property');
                        }, function (currentProperties) {
                            var currentJson = IsJsonString(currentProperties);
                            angular.forEach(currentJson, function (value, key) {
                                elem.attr(key, value);
                            }
                            });
                            //elem.removeAttr('property'); 
                            var $e = $compile(elem[0].outerHTML)(scope);
                            elem.replaceWith($e);

                        });

                    }
                }
            }]);
```

Any idea about how to solve it?

http://jsfiddle.net/3oaha6z4/6/

Comment: Could you as a jsFiddle?

Comment: I've updated the question ^_^

Comment: Are you only trying to set the attributes once or would you continue watching 'property' for changes? If you are trying to watch the values for any change in the future then you should reconsider your current approach and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: yeah I need to watch the changes... I'm working on it, but still haven't found a solution yet