# AngularJs, when directive compile new attributes, the events are not triggered if there is a scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-change

I'm a bit stuck on an directive which add attributes and recompile the element.

If I had a scope on the directive ng-change is not triggered anymore (without it it works). I based my test on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200898/angularjs-directive-to-add-attributes-the-events-are-not-triggered#new-answer?newreg=63dfa7af8215418d9363ed0f758af8ea)

The HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller='testController'>
        <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
            <input type="text" ng-model="ngModel[field.fieldName]" property="{{formParams.getProperties(field.fieldName)}}" update-attr ng-change="test()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('testController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.properties = {
            "something": {
                "style": "float:left;"
            },
                "something2": {
                "style": "float:right;"
            }
        };

        $scope.ngModel = {};
        $scope.fields = [{
            fieldName: 'something'
        }, {
            fieldName: 'something2'
        }];
        $scope.test = function () {
            alert('i dont get triggered');
        };
        $scope.formParams = {
            getProperties: function (fieldName) {
                return $scope.properties[fieldName];
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('updateAttr', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            terminate: true,
            scope: {
                ngModel : '='
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                if (angular.isDefined(attrs['property']) && attrs['property'].lenght != 0) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(attrs['property']);
                    angular.forEach(json, function (value, key) {
                        elem.attr(key, value);
                    });
                    elem.removeAttr('property');
                    var $e = $compile(elem[0].outerHTML)(scope);
                    elem.replaceWith($e);
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Here a fork of the fiddle to test with a scope on the directive: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyLLfh0/)

Do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I found why ng-change was not trigger so I share the answer:

When we add scope attribute on the directive, a new scope is created. So we have to use $scope.$parent for the compilation. I have updated the fiddle with the correction.